# how to do crypt and password_hash in php 5.6

Tags: php, crypt, password-hash

hi can anyone tell me how to use `crypt()` and and password_hash in `php 5.6` please?
because i tried and it keeps on giving me this error

> Notice: crypt(): No salt parameter was specified.

You must use a randomly generated salt and a strong hash function to produce a secure hash.

Comment: Just use `password_hash()` with the defaults. It generates a secure salt and uses the most secure hash algo available for a given PHP version, currently bcrypt. `password_hash()` is essentially just a wrapper around `crypt()` with secure defaults because hardly anyone knows how to use the function properly otherwise.

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 3):

The usage is very straight forward, following example is summing it up:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

The `password_hash()` function is actually a wrapper around the `crypt()` function, to handle the difficult parts like generating a safe salt, and to make it future proof. So there is no need to call crypt() directly.

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration is as follows:

```
string crypt ( string $str [, string $salt ] )
```

But [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) notes this:

> The **`salt`** parameter is optional. However, `crypt()` creates a weak password without the **`salt`**. PHP 5.6 or later raise an `E_NOTICE` error without it. Make sure to specify a strong enough salt for better security.

That is to say, you will just have to ignore the notice if you want to continue using the function without a salt (which would be dumb), or use a salt.

Note, however, that the documentation continues on to say this:

> `password_hash()` uses a strong hash, generates a strong salt, and applies proper rounds automatically. `password_hash()` is a simple `crypt()` wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes. **Use of `password_hash()` is encouraged.**

(That last emphasis is mine.)

Comment: @RyanVincent crypt provides the bcrypt implementation. So yeah, it does just wrap crypt internally.

Comment: It would be fatal not to provide a salt to the `crypt()` function, it then calculates a single, unsalted DES or MD5 hash, which is nearly the same as to store them plaintext. But as you wrote, there is no reason to call the crypt() function directly.